# Button not showing in the custom listview of android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have created custom Listview with ArrayAdapter. Below is my code

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                fileList) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // creates view
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                // put the image on the text view
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        fileList[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                // add margin between image and text (support various screen
                // densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

                return view;
            }
        };
```

In the above code button is not showing. How to display a button with textview and image.

Thanks

Comment: Its better to use custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

**here problem is that you use textview  ""android.R.id.text1"" of android and set in the Arraylist adapter so you only get the Textview because you return view in getview() method of Adapter**

for Button You want to create Customview.

create xmlfile cstom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

create your custom Adapter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // creates view

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cstom, null);
        Button b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.textView1);
        return view;

    }
}
```

set from your activity

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter=new MyCustomAdapter(context,list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `this`  to `get activity()`  or  `getBaseContext`

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                fileList)
```

Comment: There is no any connection between this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already a custom adapter, although it's better to create a separate class for that. Anyway for a well-done code, a `holder` is missing. Take a look how it could be done:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1,
                fileList) {

            private ViewHolder mHolder;

            private static class ViewHolder {

                TextView textView;
                Button b1;

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (view == null) {

                    mHolder = new ViewHolder();

                    LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    view = _layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

                    mHolder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    mHolder.b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                    view.setTag(mHolder);

                }
                else{

                    mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                }

                // put the image on the text view
                mHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                        fileList[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

                // add margin between image and text (support various screen
                // densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                mHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                mHolder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }

                });

                return view;
            }
        };
```